# Выполнение js кода при 'попытке' закрыть вкладку

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно выполнить код когда клиент уводит курсор за пределы документа(как бы хочет закрыть), но только не при закрытии вкладки а именно когда курсор уводит.

Comment: onMouseOut="function"

Comment: @L.Vadim спасибо.

Comment: `<body onmouseleave="alert('leave!');">` у меня отлично работает

Comment: К слову, закрыть вкладку можно и без мышки

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите использовать код после того, как курсор мышки вышел за пределы объекта, то просто в элементе пропишите следующие:

```
<div onmouseout="pasha_function();">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Если внутри div есть другие элементы, то будет срабатывать чаще чем надо

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: Да даже просто `<div onmouseout="alert(0)"><span>f</span><span>o</span><span>o</span><span>b</span><span>a</span><span>r</span></div>` :)

Comment: @andreymal у меня все работает. как надо. во всех бравсерах. покрасти див в краный цвет и проверьте

Comment: А вы поводите курсор вдоль всего содержимого блока foo, но не убирая курсор с него - нихрена не работает во всех браузерах)

Answer (score 1):

onmouseout - не работает.
Нашел другое решение, отслеживаю курсор мыши при mouseY меньше нуля выполняю код

```js
ns4 = (document.layers)? true:false
 ie4 = (document.all)? true:false

 function init() {
     if (ns4) {document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);}
     document.onmouseout=mousemove;
 }
 function mousemove(event) {
     var mouse_x = y = 0;
     if (document.attachEvent != null) {
         mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
         mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
     } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
         mouse_x = event.clientX;
         mouse_y = event.clientY;
     }
     status="x = " + mouse_x + ", y = " + mouse_y;
     if(mouse_y<=0){console.log('Всё ок')}
 }
 init()
```

Comment: если вы бы показали свой код, было бы легче понять какое решение для вас подходит. Буду признателен если в своем ответе вы поясните почему не работает? это поможет в будущем тем кто будет искать решение на свои проблемы

Comment: ie4? серьезно? :)

Comment: @Grundy onmouseout - поддерживается всеми бровсерами :)))))

Comment: Обрати внимание. что в коде, хотя ты и назвал функцию _mousemove_ используешь ее как обработчик `onmouseout`

Comment: @L.Vadim в моем случае если вешать обработчик на body то он будет срабатывать при наведении на другие элементы(по крайней мере у меня так было в chrome).

Comment: @Grundy, код в интернете нашел, решил оставить с поддержкой ie4).